# Meteor wrapAsync with Closures

Tags: javascript, meteor, closures

I am trying to use Meteor.wrapAsync

here is my code:

```
        data1 =  function(){

            connection.query('SELECT * FROM players', function(err, rows, fields){
            if (err) throw err;
            console.log(rows);
            return rows;

         });


        };

         var returndata =  Meteor.wrapAsync(data1);

         console.log(returndata);
```

The coutput that I am getting with the console.log is [Function]

Can anyone check and correct this code.

BTW: I have already have another solution this issue using the Node fibers/future in Meteor, but I would like to know some correct way to do this using Meteor.wrapAsync

Comment: Because `data1` doesn't have anything to do with asynchronous calls, `connection.query` does and you should wrap this into `Meteor.wrapAsync`

Comment: Can you please give me an example, I will try it, I will appreciate your help in this

Comment: Manu - suggest you try http://meteorpad.com/, as you can test a meteor fiddle there

Comment: @brianlmerritt - Thanks for your suggestion, I will try it.

Answer (score 0):

`Meteor.wrapAsync` forces callback to be returned as in normal sync function, to achieve it you need to do following:

```
    var asyncFunction = Meteor.wrapAsync(connection.query, connection);

    var result = asyncFunction('SELECT * FROM players');

    //operations on result
```

Didn't test this function, but I hope you get the idea and it will help you get started

Comment: Hi Sindis,

I tried this but it is not working, Actually if you see there is another function after connection.query : 

connection.query('SELECT * FROM players', function(err, rows, fields){

I hope you understand my point here I want to get result of rows.

Comment: Yes, this function is callback, and that's what you want to get synchronously, wrapAsync returns this function